# Product options/variations notice displays as an Alert

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

When I click the "Add to cart" button on a variable product, with no variation selected, the WooCommerce pops up an alert: "Please select some product options before adding this product to your cart.".

The problem is, it shows up as an Alert (browser window with Ok button). I would like to display it as a classic WooCommerce notice box within the page (or possibly to do some custom actions), but I am unable to find the responsible actions.

I tried to look for "single_add_to_cart_button". The theme is Shopkeeper, but I've looked for other themes and they seem to display it in the same manner - so I believe it is WooCommerce's default.

Any hints on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

if you remove the responsible JavaScript for this action Woocommerce by default add  html box to the product page and to do so use the following code:

```
function dequeue_script()
{
wp_dequeue_script('wc-add-to-cart-variation');
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', ' dequeue_script', 100);
```

you should put this code in your child theme functions.php

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't seem to work. It adds some sort of Wamp debug table on top of my Woo product page (no errors, it just seems like the executed method/hooks flow) and clicking on the "Add to cart" button still pops up the alert window.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just had the same issue.
I don't think you can make the solution you want without overriding the js file which will give you a headache when woocommerce updates it.
But I found another solution. I solved it by by redesigning the alert box, with inspiration in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box/22877926#22877926

The result is a nice modal, you can redesign as you wish:
[image]